# How to get authentication infomation when using spring security?

Tags: spring-security

At pages I am using tag:
 security:authorize ifAnyGranted="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN"
...
It works.
But at server side: I use SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().isAuthenticated(),it is always true. When I didn't log in, the system take anonymousUser as the log in user.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is spring security 2.x, there is `AuthorityUtils.userHasAuthority(String authority)` which you can use to make explicit check for the role.

You could iterate over `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities()` and ensure you permit operation only for the roles that you want.

Comment: Thanks, I knew this approach,I throught there was anthoer method.SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities()

Answer (score 5):

SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().isAuthenticated() will return true almost always.
use this

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
return authentication != null && !(authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken) && authentication.isAuthenticated();
```